# How to get difference between DateTime in Days:Minutes:Hours Format

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have two Dates in SQL Server table, I want difference between them in Days: Minutes: Hours Format

How to get This??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe this helps, found it on some site.

In essence, you calculate the difference in seconds. After that, you calculate days, hours and the remainder in minutes

```
DECLARE @INT INT

SET @INT = DATEDIFF(SECOND,GETDATE(),GETDATE()+1)

select 
convert(varchar(10), (@INT/86400)) + ':' + 
convert(varchar(10), ((@INT%86400)/3600)) + ':'+
convert(varchar(10), (((@INT%86400)%3600)/60)) + ':'+
convert(varchar(10), (((@INT%86400)%3600)%60)) as 'DD:HH:MM:SS'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the DATEDIFF function.